# How can I iterate through all of the Models in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, models

I would like to be able to iterate over and inspect all the models in my rails app. In pseudo-code it would look something like:

```
rails_env.models.each do |model|  
  associations = model.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)  
  ... do some stuff  
end
```

My question is how do I inspect my rails app to get a collection of the models (rails_env.models) ?

Answer (score 14):

Similar to nathanvda's response, use camelize rather than capitalize to support model files with underscores, and use String#constantize rather than Kernel.const_get.

Additionally, if you keep non-activerecord models in your models folder (e.g. a search class for consolidating search logic), you'll want to check the class is an active record model.

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app/models/*.rb').to_s].each do |filename|
  klass = File.basename(filename, '.rb').camelize.constantize
  next unless klass.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  next if klass.abstract_class?
  # do something with klass
end
```

Comment: `classify` is indeed better than `capitalize`, however it can cause problems since it will call `singularize` on names that are already singular and that can cause problems. An even better alternative would be to call `camelize` directly which is what classify calls after singularize

Comment: Edited answer to suggest use of camelize to handle the case where classify mutilates model names that end in 's' but aren't plural.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. I made these changes on my own scripts a while ago, I just forgot to update it here. I've also gone ahead and removed the call to #sub, instead using #basename second arg which can remove the file extension.

Comment: Hey thanks, I tweeked yours a bit to a one liner so it helps anyone here you go.

Dir[Rails.root.join('app/models/*.rb').to_s].map{|f| File.basename(f, '.rb').camelize.constantize }.select{|klass| klass.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)}

Comment: You'll likely want to skip any abstract classes that real models inherit from, depending on what you're doing. You can do this by adding `next if klass.abstract_class?`. I've added this to your answer to helps others.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking at ApplicationRecord models only in a modern Rails application, you can just use

```
ApplicationRecord.descendants
```

Here you can have a look at it : http://apidock.com/rails/Class/descendants

Comment: This doesn't work for me unless I've done something with the classes already.  So, in a fresh console window, ApplicationRecord.descendants returns an array with Team and User classes in it.  If I then execute Report.class.name, ApplicationRecord returns the array with the Report class now in it.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over all files in `$RAILS_ROOT\app\models' ?

For instance

```
def find_all_models
  # iterate over all files in folder
  folder = File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "app", "models")      
  Dir[File.join(folder, "*")].each do |filename|
    # remove .rb
    model_name = File.basename(filename).sub(/.rb$/, '').capitalize
    model = Kernel.const_get(model_name)
    # .. do something with your model :)
  end
end
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Rails Admin uses this code (see https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config.rb, method viable_models):

```
([Rails.application] + Rails::Engine.subclasses.collect(&:instance)).flat_map do |app|
          (app.paths['app/models'].to_a + app.config.autoload_paths).collect do |load_path|
            Dir.glob(app.root.join(load_path)).collect do |load_dir|
              Dir.glob(load_dir + '/**/*.rb').collect do |filename|
                # app/models/module/class.rb => module/class.rb => module/class => Module::Class
                lchomp(filename, "#{app.root.join(load_dir)}/").chomp('.rb').camelize
              end
            end
          end
        end.flatten.reject { |m| m.starts_with?('Concerns::') }
```

The advantage being that it loads models in associated engines, not just in your current app.

Comment: A few notes about this approach: 1) `lchomp` is not in the Ruby standard lib, so you will have to rewrite that line as `filename.gsub("#{app.root.join(load_dir)}/", '').gsub('.rb', '')` or similar, and 2) this will give you all the classes you may have defined in additional load paths (testing modules, in my case), even if they are not models, so you will have to add a line like `next unless class_name.constantize.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)` somewhere in the inner block.

Answer (score 1):

I tried implementing the above solutions under Rails 5 and they didn't quite work.  Here's a solution which finds all models which starts with "page_" (or any other prefix; just specify that):

```
def self.page_models(prefix = "page")
    models = []
    folder = File.join(Rails.root, "app", "models")
    Dir[File.join(folder, "*")].each do |filename|
     if filename =~ /models\/#{prefix}/
       klass = File.basename(filename, '.rb').camelize.constantize
       models << klass
     end
    end
    return models
end
```