# Rails Ruby easiest way to get table names of my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to iterate through every table in my database.

I've found this answer from 9 years ago:

[How can I iterate through all of the Models in my rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751857/how-can-i-iterate-through-all-of-the-models-in-my-rails-app)

With the answer apparently being:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app/models/*.rb').to_s].each do |filename|
  klass = File.basename(filename, '.rb').camelize.constantize
  next unless klass.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  next if klass.abstract_class?
  # do something with klass
end
```

The answer above is 9 years old but I can't find anything more recent. Is there an easier way for me to access this list? My end result is I want a list of every table in my database. I also have namespaced models so would need to make the above even uglier for it to work for me.

EDIT: As multiple users have pointed out models do not exist in my DB. My bad. As I said in my original post:

> My end result is I want a list of every table in my database.

Comment: _"every model in my DB"_ – the models are only known to Rails, your database isn't aware of them.

Comment: _every model in my app_ & _evey table in my DB_ are different things

Comment: Thanks for both taking the time to help.

Comment: You just checking models in app directory so what if you have components and it also got models?

Comment: I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: Your question is still unclear, because the title appears to be wrong. If you just want to know the database tables, then this is totally independent to the rails models.

Comment: _"I want a list of every table in my database"_ – only tables belonging to a model or any table?

Comment: Any table in the DB - I appreciate the term model is misused

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/154372/477037

Comment: A less sarcastic thank you for your help, that's exactly what I need

Comment: @Stefan Will that solution include view name also along with tables? if yes, how can filter out views ?

Comment: @ray what do you mean by _"view"_?

Comment: @Stefan _SQL Views_, created by raw sql fired in migration by `execute` method. I tried long time ago where I got all tables and views.

Comment: @ray oh, _those_ views. I don't know actually, my current database doesn't have tables or views ;-) It probably depends on your database and adapter. Just create a view and give it a try.